# OpenBSD threads priorities

Tags: openbsd, priority, thread, pthreads

Can anybody explain how to work with thread priorities in OpenBSD?

Information about this question in MAN pages is poor, it does not give clear understanding. In particular:

`sched_get_priority_min/max` gives range. I have OpenBSD 6.3 amd64, and range is `0-31`.

If i see default priority policy/level of first created thread of process, i see: `(SCHED_OTHER, 0)`. If `0` is lowest, how can i specify idle thread? Or priority below normal? Can i only **increase** priority? Which priority have system threads? By idea, default priority level has to be `normal`.

MAN page `pthread_setschedparam()` says: "The scheduling policy for a thread can either be `SCHED_FIFO` (first in, first out) or `SCHED_RR` (round-robin)". Why not `SCHED_OTHER`? First default thread has **this** policy.

Are these priorities for real-time or are they normal?

Can anybody make it clear?

In Windows i can set `idle` priority, and i see that this thread is scheduled only when there is no other work in a system. I can set `time_critical`, and this thread has almost all processor time.

How to resolve these tasks in OpenBSD? What are analogues of Windows priorities: `idle`, `lowest`, `below_normal`, `normal`, `above_normal`, `highest`, `time_critical`?

How to make choice between policies? `FIFO`, `OTHER` or `RR`? Are these policies equal in granting processing time when priority level is the same?

A lot of questions without answers in MAN pages.

Answer (score 2):

In `unistd.h` on OpenBSD, both [`_POSIX_PRIORITY_SCHEDULING`](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/8b23add8c74b86d0da67de43302cf21b97b028be/include/unistd.h#L82) and [`_POSIX_THREAD_PRIORITY_SCHEDULING`](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/8b23add8c74b86d0da67de43302cf21b97b028be/include/unistd.h#L100) are set to `-1`, indicating that both the Process Scheduling and Thread Execution Scheduling option are not supported (also not at runtime, as the [`sysconf` function](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/81064d433281cbb881394cc726b6ecbb9268d4ee/lib/libc/gen/sysconf.c) shows).

This means that the OpenBSD implementation does not support scheduling based on the set priorities, so all priorities set with `pthread_setschedparam` are meaningless. In fact, the source of [`pthread_setschedparam`](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/a5511fa9f431600dbd6dc2b46fc4e6b73e7d239c/lib/librthread/rthread_sched.c#L52) does also show a doubt whether `EINVAL` should be returned for priority-based scheduling policies.

So to answer your first question: you cannot work with thread priorities in OpenBSD at the moment, as this is not supported.